# How do I send an image from sdcard to social media in android?

Tags: android

In my application I have to send a picture as the attached file using social media.Here is my code.

```
private void getImage() 
{
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera /mytry.jpg"));
picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(picMessageIntent);                
}
```

Any suggestion can do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a correction to the fourth line in the function `getImage()`:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera /mytry.jpg"));
```